# Xcode will not stop indexing when model is a class when using Vapor

Tags: swift, xcode, vapor

When conforming to the Model protocol for a class in vapor I come up with a class like this:

```
import Foundation
import Vapor
import Fluent

struct Intubation: Model {
    var exists: Bool = false
    var id: Node?
    var intubationID: String
    var residentName: String
    var residentSpec: String
    var date: String
    var attending: String
    var PGY: String
    var medical: String?
    var technique: String
    var reason: String
    var dlifOverall: String
    var dsfOverall: String
    var dpfOverall: String
    var dvfOverall: String
    var dsafOverall: String
    var lowOxySatBefore: Int
    var lowOxySatDuring: Int
    var lowOxySatAfter: Int
    var lowSysBpBefore: Int
    var lowSysBpDuring: Int
    var lowSysBpAfter: Int
    var intubationOverall: String
    var comments: String


init(intubationID: String, date: String, residentName: String, residentSpec: String, attending: String, PGY: String, medical: String? = nil, technique: String, reason: String, dlifOverall: String, dsfOverall: String, dpfOverall: String, dvfOverall: String, dsafOverall: String, intubationOverall: String, comments: String, lowOxySatBefore: Int, lowOxySatDuring: Int, lowOxySatAfter: Int, lowSysBpBefore: Int, lowSysBpDuring: Int, lowSysBpAfter: Int) {

    self.intubationID = intubationID
    self.date = date
    self.residentName = residentName
    self.residentSpec = residentSpec
    self.attending = attending
    self.PGY = PGY
    self.medical = medical
    self.technique = technique
    self.reason = reason
    self.dlifOverall = dlifOverall
    self.dsfOverall = dsfOverall
    self.dpfOverall = dpfOverall
    self.dvfOverall = dvfOverall
    self.dsafOverall = dsafOverall
    self.intubationOverall = intubationOverall
    self.comments = comments
    self.lowSysBpAfter = lowSysBpAfter
    self.lowOxySatAfter = lowOxySatAfter
    self.lowSysBpBefore = lowSysBpBefore
    self.lowOxySatBefore = lowOxySatBefore
    self.lowSysBpDuring = lowSysBpDuring
    self.lowOxySatDuring = lowOxySatDuring
}

init(node: Node, in context: Context) throws {
    id = try node.extract("id")
    intubationID = try node.extract("intubationID")
    date = try node.extract("date")
    residentName = try node.extract("residentName")
    residentSpec = try node.extract("residentSpec")
    attending = try node.extract("attending")
    PGY = try node.extract("PGY")
    medical = try node.extract("medical")
    technique = try node.extract("technique")
    reason = try node.extract("reason")
    dlifOverall = try node.extract("dlifOverall")
    dsfOverall = try node.extract("dsfOverall")
    dpfOverall = try node.extract("dpfOverall")
    dvfOverall = try node.extract("dvfOverall")
    dsafOverall = try node.extract("dsafOverall")
    intubationOverall = try node.extract("intubationOverall")
    comments = try node.extract("comments")
    lowSysBpAfter = try node.extract("lowSysBpAfter")
    lowOxySatAfter = try node.extract("lowOxySatAfter")
    lowSysBpBefore = try node.extract("lowSysBpBefore")
    lowOxySatBefore = try node.extract("lowOxySatBefore")
    lowSysBpDuring = try node.extract("lowSysBpDuring")
    lowOxySatDuring = try node.extract("lowOxySatDuring")
}


func makeNode(context: Context) throws -> Node {
    return try Node(node: ["id": id,
                           "intubationID": intubationID,
                           "residentName": residentName,
                           "residentSpec": residentSpec,
                           "attending": attending,
                           "PGY": PGY,
                           "medical": medical,
                           "technique": technique,
                           "reason": reason,
                           "dlifOverall": dlifOverall,
                           "dsfOverall": dsfOverall,
                           "dpfOverall": dpfOverall,
                           "dvfOverall": dvfOverall,
                           "dsafOverall": dsafOverall,
                           "intubationOverall": intubationOverall,
                           "comments": comments,
                           "lowSysBpAfter": lowSysBpAfter,
                           "lowOxySatAfter": lowOxySatAfter,
                           "lowSysBpBefore": lowSysBpBefore,
                           "lowOxySatBefore": lowOxySatBefore,
                           "lowSysBpDuring": lowSysBpDuring,
                           "lowOxySatDuring": lowOxySatDuring])
}

static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
    try database.create("intubations") { intubations in
        intubations.id()
        intubations.string("intubationID")
        intubations.string("residentName")
        intubations.string("residentSpec")
        intubations.string("attending")
        intubations.string("PGY")
        intubations.string("medical")
        intubations.string("technique")
        intubations.string("reason")
        intubations.string("dlifOverall")
        intubations.string("dsfOverall")
        intubations.string("dpfOverall")
        intubations.string("dvfOverall")
        intubations.string("dsafOverall")
        intubations.string("intubationOverall")
        intubations.string("comments")
        intubations.int("lowSysBpAfter")
        intubations.int("lowOxySatAfter")
        intubations.int("lowSysBpBefore")
        intubations.int("lowOxySatBefore")
        intubations.int("lowSysBpDuring")
        intubations.int("lowOxySatDuring")
    }
}

static func revert(_ database: Database) throws {
    try database.delete("intubations")
}


}
```

This code does not allow Xcode to finish indexing. It gets stuck and does not finish and does not compile because it is busy trying to index. **However!** if it is marked as a `struct` and not a `class` it compiles and Xcode finishes indexing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is an issue that comes up from time to time, I'll do my best to explain.

The reason that node is able to use the dictionary literals this way is because of a vast amount of generic overloads and inference. Unfortunately, this increases compile times exponentially to the point of occasionally causing compilation to not be possible.

In Vapor 2 (currently in alpha) we have done some work to enforce this a bit more and make it more clear for users. For now, let's solve the issue at hand.

Break out your makeNode function as follows:

```
var node = Node.object([:])
node["key"] = try value.makeNode()
// .. continue
return node
```

This is a little more long form but will help compiler a great deal

**Vapor 2**

It's not released yet, but while I'm here so the answer doesn't go stale. (The above code will also still work!)

```
var node = Node([:])
try node.set("key.path", value)
// ... continue
return node
```